# Data Security using LSB &DCT - error from matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, dct

% i got error DC11=dct2(C11);DCC12=dct2(C12);......Conversion to double from cell is not possible. 
  %Data security using LSB &DCT steganography in Images '

```
%step1:Divide cover image to 8*8 Block    
C=imread('E:\sofia1.jpg');
C=C(:,:,1);
[r1 c1]=size(C);
 row=r1;
 col=c1; 
  % a punch of code to make a square image C with equal dimension (not mentioned) 
 C=mat2cell(C,[32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 ],[32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32]); % divide the matrix   
  C11=C{1,1}; C12=
  {1,2};C13=C{1,3};C14=C{1,4};C15=C{1,5};C16=C{1,6};C17=C{1,7};C18=C{1,8}; 
 %step2:perform 2D-DCT on each Block 
 DC11=dct2(C11);DCC12=dct2(C12);    
 DC13=dct2(C13);DC14=dct2(C14);DC15=dct2(C15);DC16=dct2(C16);DC17=dct2(C17);  
 DC18=dct2(C18);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo. You wrote `C12={1,2}` when you meant to write `C12=C{1,2}`.

To explain your error message, `{1,2}` is a cell, while `C{1,2}` is a matrix with numbers, which is what dct2 likes.

---

I also have some suggestions to improve your code layout.

- You don't have to hardcode [32 32 32 ... 32] in the mat2cell command.
- You should check that your image is perfectly divisible to the number of submatrices requested.
- You don't have to hardcode the cells, such as C11, C12 and so on.
- Optional: `C` is initially the loaded image, but then set to the cell array. If you want to keep both, you want different variables.

I am confused why you divide the matrix is submatrices of 32x32 size. Your top comment says 8x8 blocks, which is also what I know to be the norm. For that, you need to provide matrices of [8 8 8 ... 8].

```
%step1:Divide cover image to 8*8 Block    
cover = imread('E:\sofia1.jpg');
cover = cover(:,:,1);
[row col] = size(cover);
rowBlocks = row/8; if rowBlocks ~= floor(rowBlocks) disp('Invalid row size'); end
colBlocks = col/8; if colBlocks ~= floor(colBlocks) disp('Invalid col size'); end

% a punch of code to make a square image C with equal dimension (not mentioned) 
C = mat2cell(cover, ones(1, rowBlocks)*8, ones(1, colBlocks)*8); % divide the matrix   
for i = 1:size(C,1)
    for j = 1:size(C,2)
        D{i,j} = dct2(C{i,j});
    end
end
```

At the moment, if the image size isn't divisible by 8, it will just print a warning and carry on with the code. Eventually, `mat2cell` will complain about this. You have two options for how to deal with the warning. Either instantly exit the program, or resize the image so that both rows and columns are divisible by 8.